# FastAPI value_error.missing

Tags: python, amazon-s3, fastapi, valueerror, pydantic

```
# Define a global variable to store the uploaded file
uploaded_file = None


@app.post("/upload/")
async def upload_file(form_data: ValidatedUploadFile = Form(...)):
    global uploaded_file  # Use the global variable
    try:
        pdf_file = form_data.file
        # Check if the uploaded file has a PDF content type or filename extension
        if not pdf_file.content_type or not pdf_file.content_type.startswith(
                "application/pdf"):
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Uploaded file is not a PDF")
        if form_data.password is not None:
            # Create a temporary file to save the uploaded PDF

            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
                temp_file.write(pdf_file.file.read())
                temp_file.seek(0)
            print("Printing temp file", temp_file.name)
            # Attempt to open the PDF with the provided password
            try:
                pdf = pikepdf.open(temp_file.name, password=form_data.password)
            except pikepdf.PasswordError:
                return {"message": "Invalid password for the PDF."}
            # Remove the password from the PDF
            pdf.save("unlocked.pdf")
            uploaded_file = 'unlocked.pdf'
            # Upload the modified PDF to AWS S3
            try:
                s3.Bucket(AWS_BUCKET_NAME).upload_file(Filename="unlocked.pdf", Key=pdf_file.filename)
                print("Upload Complete")
            except Exception as e:
                return {"message": f"Error uploading to AWS S3: {str(e)}"}
            print("Entering Convert Data")
            result = await convert_data()
            print("Returned from convert data")
            # Remove the temporary files after processing
            # Now, you can close the temporary file explicitly
            temp_file.close()
            print("temp closed")
            # Remove the temporary files after processing
            os.remove("unlocked.pdf")
            print("Removed temp file")
            return {"message": "File uploaded successfully", "result": result}
        else:
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
                temp_file.write(pdf_file.file.read())
                temp_file.seek(0)
                # Store the uploaded file in the global variable
                uploaded_file = temp_file.name
            # Upload the file to AWS S3
            try:
                s3.Bucket(AWS_BUCKET_NAME).upload_file(Filename=temp_file.name, Key=pdf_file.filename)
            except Exception as e:
                return {"message": f"Error uploading to AWS S3: {str(e)}"}
            print("Entering Convert Data")
            result = await convert_data()
            # Remove the temporary file after processing
            # Now, you can close the temporary file explicitly
            temp_file.close()
            os.remove(temp_file.name)
            return {"message": "File uploaded successfully", "result": result}
    except NoCredentialsError:
        return {"error": "AWS credentials not found."}
    except HTTPException as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"}
```

This is code
this is my pydantic model

```
class ValidatedUploadFile(BaseModel):
    file: UploadFile
    password: Optional[str] = None
```

[This is error I am getting can anybody help me solve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rweaJ.png)

I'm building a FastAPI application that handles file uploads, and I'm using Pydantic for request validation.
I have a FastAPI route that expects both a file upload and an optional password field. The validation is done using a custom Pydantic model. However, when testing the endpoint using Postman, I'm encountering an error with the message `"field required"` in the response. This error seems to be related to the `form_data` field being missing or incorrectly formatted in the request body. I've double-checked the field names and types in Postman, and they seem to match the FastAPI route definition. Still, I'm getting this error. I'd appreciate any guidance on resolving this issue and ensuring that the file upload and optional password are correctly processed in my FastAPI application.